# Asp.net Core 5.0 Linq Take(1).ElementAt(index)

Tags: linq, sorting, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-5.0

I have a long `Linq` query and I'm trying to take one data in any index of that query.

My query is :

```
        public IEnumerable<WebFairField> WebFairFieldForFair(Guid ID,int index)
        {
            return TradeTurkDBContext.WebFairField.Where(x => x.DataGuidID==ID)
             .Include(x => x.Category)
             .ThenInclude(x=>x.MainCategory).AsSplitQuery()
             //
             .Include(x=>x.FairSponsors)
             .ThenInclude(x=>x.Company)
             .ThenInclude(x=>x.FileRepos).AsSplitQuery()
             //
             .Include(x=>x.WebFairHalls.Take(1).ElementAt(index)) //Thats the point where i stuck*
             .ThenInclude(x=>x.HallSeatingOrders)
             .ThenInclude(x=>x.Company)
             .ThenInclude(x=>x.FileRepos).AsSplitQuery()
             //
             .Include(x=>x.HallExpertComments).AsSplitQuery()
             .Include(x=>x.Products).AsSplitQuery()
             .Include(x=>x.FairSponsors).AsSplitQuery()
             .AsNoTrackingWithIdentityResolution()
             .ToList();
        }
```

when I do that it gives me an error : `Collection navigation access can be filtered by composing Where, OrderBy,ThenBy,Skip or Take operations.`
I know I have to sort that data but I don't know how to do it. Can anyone show me how should I sort my data of that query ?

**Thanks for any suggestion!!**

Comment: Something like `Skip(index - 1).Take(1)` ? Also possibly you will need to apply some ordering to get consistent results.

Comment: Also having `ElementAt` after `Take(1)` one does not make any sense in any context I can imagine.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Guru it worked but i wanna ask something. im doing that action for my paginiation but i wanna learn if there is a much better way than im doing. is there a much better way to do that ?

Comment: For me it would take require a little bit more understanding of your project's domain. Possibly - yes, but it depends.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## The error

As you have mentioned, the line of

```
.Include(x=>x.WebFairHalls.Take(1).ElementAt(index)) //Thats the point where i stuck*
```

is causing the error. Basically you `Take` the first element and then try to call [ElementAt](https://www.javatpoint.com/linq-elementat-method). This is a problem technically, because you need to convert your collection to [IEnumerable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.elementat?view=net-5.0) in order to be able to call `ElementAt`.

It is also a logical error, since if you take a single element, then it does not make sense to try and call `ElementAt` for it.

## Skip

As Guru Strong pointed out, you can Skip, as `Skip(index - 1).Take(1)` which skips the first index - 1 elements and then takes the next one, which is the index'th element.

## Sort

If you need to sort, call [OrderBy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby?view=net-5.0). If you need several sorting criteria, then use [ThenBy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.thenby?view=net-5.0).